# Have image within div without its attributes

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image within a div which has a dim background colour, this is also affecting my picture. How can i place my image inside the same div but have it a layer on top so it's not affected by the dimming colour.

```
.testimonial .cover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 7, 11, .87)
}

<div class="testimonial">
   <div class="cover"></div>
   <img "This is the image i want to be a layer on top">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try to do div inside a div and in the first one (the background) put the color and in the inner one put the image...

Comment: I've tried that already to no avail

Comment: where is the `.cover` element in your html? `background-color` is not supposed to affect the opacity of the div's content.

Comment: Remove .cover! Up at the top

Comment: Seems like you have an `opacity` property somewhere in your CSS. The `background-color` property should not be affecting the `<img>` in any way.

Comment: Also close the css line with ;

Comment: On my website anomstudios.com navigate to process, the image in the middle is what i'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 7, 11, .87);
```

contains an opacity parameter (0.87). This opacity (partly transparent) affects the contents of that DIV (for example text), but it should not affect images that are inside an `<img>` tag

Still, if you change that value `.87` to `1.0`, the overall impression will certainly be different.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZZOLO 
If you change the background color's opacity, the (light blue) image won't change.

Comment: On my website anomstudios.com navigate to process, the image in the middle is what i'm having problems with.

Comment: Ah - but there it's the other way round: The DIV with that background color is _on_top_of_ the image  (`.cover`is _inside_  the DIV with ID `#testimonial-trigger`, and the image is a background image of that element).  To get what you want, either move '.cover' out of `#testimonial-trigger` or simply erase that `background-color`setting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="testimonial>
   <div class="test">
      <img "This is the image i want to be a layer on top">
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.test{
background-color:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The background color should have no effect on the image **at all**. Do you see the missing " (double quote) in your example code after `<div class="testimonial>` ? There's your error....

See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/sz10aghg/), it has a low (.3) rgba alpha value not affecting the image.

BTW: the last attribute in a CSS rule does **not** require a ; (semi-colon). Actually, I remove them in my code all the time.

Comment: On my website anomstudios.com navigate to process, the image in the middle is what i'm having problems with.

Comment: Ahh, well, in your explanation you did not mention that the image was a `background: url()` of the parent `div`, which is rather crucial. A quick solution would be to remove `background-color`